# Flutter - Set up Google Maps

Tags: flutter, api, google-maps

I believe I have set up everything correctly; yet I keep getting Authorization Error while trying to load Google Maps. I get a blank screen with the plus/minus buttons.

Android Manifest

```
        </activity>
    ...
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
           android:value="@string/GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY"/>
```

Enabled Maps for Android

Enabled Maps for iOS

Tried a whole lot of other stuff

Debug Console:

...

Successfully registered with Phenotype.

E/Google Maps Android API( 9624): Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.

...

I can share screen if someone can help.

Comment: have you replaced the "API_KEY" with an working API key? seems to be a API Error.

Comment: "@string/GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY" fetches the API key from another file. The file contains the correct API key (as there is only one API key in the Google Console which I have copied to the file).

Comment: if it says auth error it mostly with the API key. instead retrieving from another file try directly putting the key there.

Comment: I did that, same result.